# How to correctly get system language in Windows 7 or later

Tags: delphi, delphi-2007

I need to extract the user's Windows language, and i'm using the function below. However i tested in my current machine (it's op english), but the function return is "Portuguese (Brazil)".

Actually my machine was in this language originally, but after i installed a new language pack and it's now in English, not Portuguese ; so i assume the function below is not working properly. Is there another alternative ?

Thanks

```
function GetWindowsLanguage: string;
var
  WinLanguage: array [0..50] of char;
begin
  VerLanguageName(GetSystemDefaultLangID, WinLanguage, 50);
  Result := StrPas(WinLanguage);
end;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to get the information about which language is being used for Windows UI by current user you should use [GetUserDefaultUILanguage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winnls/nf-winnls-getuserdefaultuilanguage) function instead of `GetSystemDefaultLangID`

If the current user has not set any language then System Default UI Language is returned.

For Delphi 2007, you'll need to declare the function, as it didn't exist at the time that version was released. Note that doing so statically as shown here will mean your app will no longer run on versions of Windows prior to Windows 2000.

```
function GetUserDefaultUILanguage: LANGID; stdcall; external 'kernel32';

function GetUsersWindowsLanguage: string;
var
  WinLanguage: array [0..50] of char;
begin
  VerLanguageName(GetUserDefaultUILanguage, WinLanguage, 50);
  Result := WinLanguage;
end;
```

Comment: I'm not on a develpment machine so I can't currently write you a code example. But I do believe that you can change your code by simply swapping the method you are currently using with the one that I'm suggesting as both return language ID

Comment: Thank you but by doing so i get "[DCC Error] E2003 Undeclared identifier: 'GetUserDefaultUILanguage'"

Comment: @delphirules: That's because Delphi 2007 came out long before that function existed. You'll need to write your own declaration. Declare it just like the others, and the documentation tells you what system DLL it's in (kernel32).

Comment: @SilverWarior: I upvoted your answer. I haven't yet deleted mine because of the comments Rudy left about testing; I'll leave it until he has a chance to report those test results.

Comment: @KenWhite Thank you but unfortunatelly i don't know how to do it. I'd be very glad if you could post a complete working code, please

Comment: @delphirules: See the edit I made to this answer. I compiled and tested it (along with the rest of the code from this answer) in Delphi 2007 on Windows 7.

Comment: @KenWhite It worked ! Will i have any problem if i run my apps only on Windows 7 and later ?

Comment: See my comments to Ken's answer: on my laptop, which was only ever freshly installed as English, but has German locale settings, `GetUserDefaultUILanguage` returns the installation and UI settings (English), while the other two: `GetSystemDefaultLangID` and `GetUserDefaultLangID` return the locale settings (German).

Comment: @delphirules: The documentation says it is supported on Windows 2000 and later.

Answer (score 3):

You want [GetUserDefaultLangID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winnls/nf-winnls-getuserdefaultlangid) instead. If your machine was set for Portugese when Windows was installed, that is the default language for your system. The user's currently selected language is the one chosen by the logged in user.  (See the *Remarks* on the linked page.)

```
function GetUsersWindowsLanguage: string;
var
  WinLanguage: array [0..50] of char;
begin
  VerLanguageName(GetUserDefaultLangID, WinLanguage, 50);
  Result := StrPas(WinLanguage);
end;
```

Comment: Tried it, but it still returns 'Portuguese (Brazil)' : /

Comment: Please [edit] your question and explain what you did (other than install the English language pack) to make English your current Windows language.

Comment: Actually i only installed a new language pack, just this.

Comment: Then your default language is still Portugese, and both functions are correct. Installing a language pack does not change the system or user language.

Comment: Using `GetUserDefaultLanguageID` only returns the ID of  selected language in regional settings. This is not necessary the sam leanguage as the Windows UI language. But if you want to get language ID of the language that is used for Windows UI you need to use [GetuserDefaultUILanguage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winnls/nf-winnls-getuserdefaultuilanguage)

Comment: @SilverWarior: If you add an answer providing that information, I'll delete mine.

Comment: More bizarre, i tested in a machine that never had Portuguese as original language, always is English, and the function still returns 'Portuguese (Brazil)'... maybe it's returning my app language, which is really portuguese ?

Comment: The function that Ken sugested returns the language ID based on your regional settings and not based on Windows UI. That is probably the reason why it returns Portuguese even on a machine that never had Portuguese UI language installed

Comment: FWIW, not an answer, but you can fully omit `StrPas()`. Just assign directly. That is what `StrPas()` does too, internally. Just take a look at the source code.

Comment: @SilverWarrior: can't check here, but my laptop at home has always had English Windows (i.e. it was empty when I installed English Windows). But I use German regional settings for numbers, dates, keyboard, etc., **except for the language**. I'll check if what you say is true, as soon as I can.

Comment: My test with `GetUserDefaultUILanguage` shows: **"English (United States)"**. So again: German locale settings, but English (US) as fresh installation language.

Comment: FWIW, if I use `GetSystemDefaultLangID` or `GetUserDefaultLangID`, in both cases I get **"German (Germany)"**.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis Exactly. Functions `GetSystemDefaultLangID` and `GetUserDefaultLangID` are returning language ID used in locale settings. But OP was clearly asking about language that is being used for Windows UI and could only be added by installing additional language packs. As for locale langauge you can chose any without needing to install any additional files to the computer.